# Disable kernel logging during initialization

Tags: linux-kernel, logs

I'm using a Linux image generated with buildroot for an embedded system.
I recently disabled some modules from being generated with the image and now some logging messages are being shown during the kernel intitialization, after uboot has done its job.

This is the first message that appears:

```
Starting logging: Jan  1 00:00:03 mdb_linux syslog.info syslogd started: BusyBox v1.21.1
```

and then lots of these messages start flooding the boot process. Most of them are kern.warn and kern.info.

What should I do to disable them?

Comment: check this solution: http://superuser.com/questions/351387/how-to-stop-kernel-messages-from-flooding-my-console#517043

Comment: I've tried adding loglevel=1 in uboot just to see if all the messages would go away, but they still showed up.

Comment: Actually, I've changed the bootargs in U-Boot and I've saved the environment. But when I cat /proc/cmdline, the loglevel is not there and, after reboot, the loglevel is gone. Apparently, it was not saved at all.

Comment: Further research leads me to believe it has something to do with syslogd and klogd. They seem to start logging by default.

Comment: it seems you can set `kern.info and kern.warn` to certain file rather than console in syslog.conf see http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl5_syslogc.htm 
if you are using ubuntu you can set the same in `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` file. hope this helps